# Magento 2.3.3: Widget layout - Is it possible to add a widget to products by attribute?

Tags: layout, product-attribute, widget, widgets, magento2.3.3

I know Magento allows for widgets to be placed on specific products but I need to take it further. I need the option to allow me to filter by product attribute and apply widget to products with those attribute. Thanks.